# new line for String.format works on console, but in not in email

Tags: java, string, email, formatting

This is what I set as property

```
props.setProperty(EmailSender.MAIL_BODY,
                      "This is an automated email.%nZip Path: %s\nAdditional Text: %s\nThank you.");
```

and I use it as

```
  private String generateEmailBody(final EmailRequest diagnosticRequest) {
    final String bodyTemplate = getExistingProperty(MAIL_BODY);
    return String.format(bodyTemplate, diagnosticRequest.getZipFilePath(),
                      diagnosticRequest.getTextFromCustomer());
  }
```

When I run test, I see on console as following

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is an automated email.
Zip Path: zipPath
Additional Text: text
Thank you.
.
```

But when I receive email, I see it as

```
This is an automated email. Zip Path: zipPath Additional Text: text Thank you.
```

Why newline is not preserved?

I even tried `%n`, `%n%n`, but none works

Comment: So I'll throw this out there:  did you try `\n` or `\r\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your content type is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii`

this means that `\n` or `%n` will not work as during HTML rendering spaces and new lines are ignored (at least most of them), replace new line character with `<br>` - this is new line in html

another solution is to include your text into `<pre>....</pre>` tags, this will preserve original formatting

of course you can change content type to `text/plain` too

Comment: @Makoto but HTML ignore spaces and new lines

Comment: @Makoto yes, content rendered as html because of content type property